# Problem after erasing the HD of a brand new Mac (OS X Yosemite) with Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, install, core-storage

I cannot reinstall OS X Yosemite now, as there's no hard drive I could see.

I had erased the HD with the idea that it will create a new partition but it didn't, so now I can't see a hard disk on disk utility. I have tried with diskutil command, but didn't succeed.

[image: Disk Utility First Aid]

[image: Disk Utility Partition]

Comment: Could you try to remember which action lead you to this total volume destruction (most probably named Macintosh HD)?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have a CoreStorage Logical Volume Group without a CoreStorage Logical Volume now. You may delete your Logical Volume Group (-> step 4) or restore a Logical Volume (-> step 7).

Requirements: Booted to Recovery Mode

1. Please quit Disk Utility.
2. Open Utilities/Terminal in the menubar
3. Enter `diskutil cs list` and hit enter. The output will look like this:

   ```
   CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
   |
   +-- Logical Volume Group 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB
       =========================================================
       Name:         Macintosh HD
       Status:       Online
       Size:         250640592384 B (250.2 GB)
       Free Space:   6111232 B (6.1 MB)
       |
       +-< Physical Volume 907FCDE2-0C62-4951-A39E-36F19244FDB7
       |   ----------------------------------------------------
       |   Index:    0
       |   Disk:     disk0s2
       |   Status:   Online
       |   Size:     250634481152 B (250.2 GB)
   ```
4. To delete the Logical Volume Group enter:

   ```
   diskutil cs delete lvgUUID
   ```

   The lvgUUID is the UUID of the Logical Volume Group and usually the first listed.
   In the above example:

   ```
   diskutil cs delete 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB
   ```

   This will delete your CoreStorage LVG and reformat it as an unencrypted HFS+ volume.
5. Enter `exit`, hit enter and quit Terminal
6. Open Disk Utility to format your disk like you want.
7. After step 3 you may create alternatively a new CoreStorage Logical Volume in your orphaned LVG by entering:

   ```
   diskutil cs createVolume lvgUUID jhfs+ NewVolName Size
   ```

   Using the above example

   ```
   diskutil cs createVolume 5B8350BF-20EF-4199-82E6-129EFF19E9EB jhfs+ MyMac 100%
   ```

   would create a new full sized (≈ 249.5 GB) Journaled HFS+ volume with the name 'MyMac'